# html img width cannot show some smaller image?

Tags: html, image, width

My Wordpress post tries to show an image with HTML code like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/15925638948/posts/10152127553183949" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none;">
    <img title="CBS Moving Forward With ‘How I Met Your Dad’" alt="" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTA5MzAzNTcyNjZeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDUyMzE1MTk@._V1._SY317_.jpg" width="620" align="">
</a>
```

However, the image cannot be displayed. Chrome & Safari shows a white box with a small image in the middle (the case that the image cannot be displayed). Firefox shows nothing for the image part but a blank line.

If I remove this line

```
width="620"
```

the image displays.

What's the rule about this width and the actual image width? It seems working fine for most cases but not for smaller images? How do I dynamically change the width to best fit my design?

Answer (score 1):

It actually works fine for me (in all browsers). My guess would be that since no height was specified, the browser was interpreting it as 0. This explains the way in which Firefox was rendering the image, but not the others. There is also the possibility that some other code (from the theme, a plugin, or elsewhere) is interfering.

Comment: hm... it actually works after I tested it with nothing but the code... must be some theme interference... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well one thing you may not know is the % function usable in HTML for many things.

for example using this code:

```
...
width:50%;
...
```

would allow the width of the child object to be 50% of that of the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is related to this question

[Image getting 403 forbidden when deployed to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135965/image-getting-403-forbidden-when-deployed-to-server)

It's not about the width, sorry for the misleading.